# Updating Data (practice)

Tags: mysql

So I'm given a practice query to increase or UPDATE employees salaries by 20% if their rating is above 5.

```
UPDATE company
SET salary = (salary+salary * 20/100)
WHERE rating > 5;
SELECT * FROM company;
```

My question is,why is it correct to write this part of the code (salary + salary) and simply not (salary * 20/100). Thank you.

Comment: You could also do something like salary * 1.2. Otherwise, you are decreasing their salary. 20,000 * 20/100 = 4,000.  My idea is 20,000 * 1.2 = 24,000. Or your first attempt, salary + salary * 20/100 is 20,000 + 20,000 * 20/100 = 24,000.

Comment: What I mean is I ran the code and it is correct. But there's a cap in my understanding because everything else make sense to me except that one part that I've mentioned.

Comment: It is a math thing I believe.  You then want to compare the total salary lets say 30K to the equation of 20% of 30K so you do need to put salary twice like you suggested.  I don't know if that explains it to you The new salary would be 36,000 in this example.   But you are taking the existing salary and then adding to it the equation of the new salary, so the first salary is for addition and the second one is for the multiply/div part.  Does that clear it up?  (I couldn't edit what i posted so hope this fixes it)

Comment: If you have a Salary of $30,000.

Base Salary + ( Base Salary X 20 / 100)

You take what they are making, and then add the new increase to it so you have the new total salary this way.  Without that, you would just have the increase of $6000 by its self.  If that makes sense to you I would retype the comments into a better Answer if you would mark it.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the salary by 20%, you have to add 20% of the salary to the old salary. For instance, if the salary is `100`, you add `20` to to get the new salary `120`.

To calculate 20% of something, you multiply it by `20/100`. So `salary * 20/100` is 20% of the salary.

Then you add this to the old salary, so the complete formula is `salary + (salary * 20/100)`.

If you just multiply the salary by `20/100`, the result would be `20`, not `120`.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing more than elementary mathematics.

Consider what your statement is currently doing: `salary = (salary+salary * 20/100)`

Fortunately, because of order of precedence, multiplication and division is followed by addition, not vice-versa, so you can also read it as `salary = salary + (salary * (20/100))`

*20 divided by 100* is 0.2 (ie 20%) so if you simply had `salary = salary * 0.2` you can see you'd have 20% of the original salary - not what you want, so you add this 20% to the existing salary to result in the original salary *plus* 20%.

The more common approach - I believe - is the equivalent and more obvious `salary = salary * 1.2`, ie multiply the value by itself plus 0.2 of its value.

It follows that you could reverse this to *remove* 20% by dividing by 1.2